# Android App Language doesn't change for the menu items although it changed everything else like fragments and activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am localizing an android application and adding change language button. But as soon as i click the language button, it change that language for all activity and fragments as i put in the string folder but the menu items language in slidebar doesn't change language. This is my language change code.
`
public class Settings extends Fragment {
Locale myLocale;

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        ///String [] values =
                /// {"Please Select Language","Myanmar","English",};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        /// ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
        /// adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        /// spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int pos, long id) {

                if (pos == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            "You have selected Myanmar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    saveLocale("my");
                } else if (pos == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    saveLocale("en");
                }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });

        return v;

    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {


        // Create a new Locale object
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        // Create a new configuration object
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        // Set the locale of the new configuration
        config.locale = myLocale;
        // Update the configuration of the Accplication context
        getResources().updateConfiguration(
                config,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        );


    }
    public void saveLocale(String language) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("USER_LANGUAGE", language);
        editor.commit();
        LoadLanguage ();
        FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.setReorderingAllowed (false);
        t.detach(this).attach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }
    public void LoadLanguage(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = sharedPreferences.getString("USER_LANGUAGE","");
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this function in mainactivity and make sure you call it in main activity. In this case, the app just need to reload or restart to apply changes to all that i don't know.

```
public void LoadLanguage(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = sharedPreferences.getString("USER_LANGUAGE","");
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```